# PostgreSQL migration from TEXT to INTEGER with existing data which can be null

Tags: sql, postgresql, flyway, alter-table

I'm trying to perform alter table column change from `TEXT` to `INTEGER` in PostgreSQL database like below:

```
ALTER TABLE analyzer_parser_event
ALTER COLUMN error_id TYPE INTEGER USING (error_id::integer);
```

The thing is that I have already existing data where `error_id` can be `NULL`. That causes an error:

```
Statement  : ALTER TABLE analyzer_parser_event
    ALTER COLUMN error_id TYPE INTEGER USING (error_id::integer)

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "NULL"
```

I was trying with `NULLIF` instruction but it haven't helped me.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: is this really NULL or is it rather a string with the letters 'NULL' that the DBMS is complaining about? You haven't made the column non-nullable, so nulls should be no problem, I guess.

Comment: can you provide a fillde https://dbfiddle.uk/nY8gmqKJ that shows that problem, as NULL shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I'll check it in 7 hours time. I've already  closed my notebook because it's night in my timezone. Thanks :) I'll let you know if there is actually "NULL"  or not

Comment: `NULLIF` works for me . Try something like: `ALTER COLUMN error_id TYPE INTEGER USING  nullif(error_id, 'NULL')::integer;`

Comment: Actually the problem was with "NULL" value ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to determine if error_id is numeric with

```
select * from analyzer_parser_event where not textregexeq(error_id,'^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?$');
```

evaluate the result and then you can simply update the records

```
update analyzer_parser_event set error_id='0' where not textregexeq(error_id,'^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?$');
```

Greetings, Alejandro